# Custom Dropdown menu not working with links

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a custom menu using a tutorial I found.

The problem I'm running into is not the implementation, but something that stops me from clicking through links. When, I have the menu "opened" and when I click on a say link, it just closes the menu and for a quick second I see it highlight the whole box instead of the link.

Here are a few screenshots. You can hover over the links (they turn purple when hovered), but when you click on an individual link it tends to just click out of the whole menu instead of sending you to the said page. But when, I hover over it I can see that it is showing the link in the bottom left hand corner of my browser. I just can't seem to figure out what is happening with the click out instead of the url sending you to the page.

http://cl.ly/image/0S2F2c3h3g1o
(hover screen shot)

http://f.cl.ly/items/3P1h27323B203E2J0N41/clickout.png 
(clickout)

When I try to click on any link, I just get this blue box, and it closes the menu instead of sending you to the linked page.

This is the HTML that I have hooked up

```
   <!-- MOBILE MENU / -->
<nav id="mobile-menu">
    <div id="mobmenu" class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="1">
        <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
            <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="/work">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="/notes">NOTES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</nav>
<!-- / MOBILE MENU -->
```

This is the Javascript.

```
        function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('#mobmenu') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('active');
            });

        });

    </script>
```

And the CSS.

```
#mobile-menu {
    width: 320px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background: #050607 url(images/menu_closed.png) no-repeat center top;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 17px;
    outline: none;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.dropdown-menu::after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
/* ACTIVE STATE */
.dropdown-menu .dropdown {
    background: #050607;
    height: 1000px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown  li { 
    position: relative; 
    top: 10px; 
    z-index: 99;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown li a {
    border-top: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    pointer-events: visible;
    padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 9999999999999999999999;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown li:nth-child(5)  {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown li:hover a { background: #050607; color: #605e90; }
.dropdown-menu.active .dropdown {
    -moz-animation: fadein .3s linear;
    -webkit-animation: fadein .3s linear;
    -ms-animation: fadein .3s linear;
    animation: fadein .3s linear;
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1.0;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu.active:active {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu.active::after { 
    border-color: #000; 
    margin-top: -3px; 
}
.dropdown-menu.active {
    background: #050607 url(images/menu_open.png) no-repeat center top;
    outline: none;
}
```

Thanks! :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `obj.opts` click event handler fires, the `obj.dd` click event handler will also fire. To prevent this, call the `stopPropagation` function of the event object passed to the handler.

See here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hwTUZ/1/

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! I knew it had to be something in the JS. I just couldn't figure it out. I kept tinkering with the return false, and doing preventDefault, but nothing worked! Thanks a bunch for taking your time to figure this out :)

Comment: Hey, you wouldn't know how to hide the menu links? They're um, clickable even if the menu isn't expanded.

Comment: You can do this by modifying the CSS of the dropdown class to make it hidden by default ("display: none;"), and then toggling the visibility when the user clicks on the div. Also, some of the javascript code is redundant if you simply want to have a dropdown list of links. Here's a fixed version with the redundant javascript stripped out: http://jsfiddle.net/7YS3W/2/